# Finding an element in a nested list however we don't know the list

Tags: python, list

As I mentioned in title, how can we find an element in a nested list but the user creates the list. For instance:

```
[’t’,[’q’,[’d’,1],[’p’,7],[’e’,[’i’,1],[’r’,5]]],[’i’,[’o’,5],[’y’,3],[’f’,8]]]
```

I want to find `3`'s index.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by index. Is it the index of 3 in `['y', 3]` or the index of `['y', 3]` in the outer list ... ?

Comment: the index of ['y', 3] in the outer list

Comment: `['y', 3]` is not a member of the outer list, since it occurs in another list that in turn is member of the outer list. There are three indexes involved in the example you have given: 1, 2, 1. It is not clear what you want, and you should at least show what you tried.

Comment: yes I want to find 1,2,1 but what if user creates the list as [1,2,t,[y,3]] ?

Comment: @bartukilickaya, then it should be 3,1.

Comment: What have you tried so far @bartukilickaya?

Comment: @Ivan the problem is we don't know the input so I have to find it iteratively or recursively.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then one approach to solve it is using backtracking. You can recursively search the element in nested lists while keeping track of indexes so far. When element is found, you return from the function. Here's the code for the approach

```py
_list1 = [
    't',
    [
        'q',
        ['d',1],
        ['p',7],
        [
            'e',
            ['i',1],
            ['r',5]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'i',
        ['o',5],
        ['y',3],
        ['f',8]
    ]
]
_list2 = [
    1,
    2,
    't',
    ['y',3]
]

def find_ind_rec(current_list, indexes, search_key):
    for index,element in enumerate(current_list): # Iterate through the list
        if element == search_key: # If element equals to the search_key, return True
            indexes.append(index) # Add current index
            return True
        elif isinstance(element,list): # If element is another list (nested list), recursively search for search_key
            indexes.append(index) # Add current index
            if find_ind_rec(element,indexes,search_key): # If search_key found in this nested list, return true
                return True
            # Otherwise, backtrack!
            indexes.pop()
    return False # If search_key not found, return False

indexes = [] # Initially empty
find_ind_rec(_list1,indexes,['y',3]) # Search ['y',3] in example _list1
print(indexes)
indexes = [] # Initially empty
find_ind_rec(_list1,indexes,['i',1]) # Search ['i',1] in example _list1
print(indexes)
indexes = [] # Initially empty
find_ind_rec(_list2,indexes,3) # Search 3 in example _list2
print(indexes)
indexes = [] # Initially empty
find_ind_rec(_list2,indexes,5) # Search 5 in example _list2 --> Not found
print(indexes)
```

---

Output

```
[2, 2]
[1, 3, 1]
[3, 1]
[]
```